# Сохранения в WebGL

Tags: unity3d, xml, сериализация, webgl

Итак, как сохранить файлы(сохранения) Web-игры (Unity WebGJ) на компьютере клиента?
С десктоп-версией я использую сериализацию в xml, а как сделать подобное в Web-версии?
Желательно именно сохранение файла на ПК пользователя, а не запись в БД

Comment: Если это как-то поможет, то сам проект опубликован на itch.io

Comment: `xml` для чего? В `Unity3D` есть [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html). Зачем что то придусывать? [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) работает и в WebGL.